# Usage of "scienter"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, legalese

"Scienter" is most commonly used as a noun in the following contexts:

"Whether the corporation acted *with* scienter in defrauding investors." (In this case, it appears to be the object of the preposition, therefore a noun.)

"Whether scienter was one of the elements that was required to be proven." (Also used as a noun.)

I recently stumbled upon the following usage: "Whether prosecutors must show that a defendant *had* scienter."

I'm not sure if scienter can be a state that an individual possesses. Is this an appropriate usage of the word? If not, what would be the correct usage?

Comment: *Scienter* is not a word in normal usage.  It does have currency in certain legal contexts: unless you give the source of your quotations, it is impossible to say anything further.

Comment: Never seen the word before, and, based on your context, it is likely a legal term, with no meaning outside of the legal practice.

Comment: @HotLicks, its mere virtue as a "legal term"--as you put it--does not mean it is not worth consideration. I fail to understand how this comment contributes to the solution of the question; which is about an __English__ word. Nevertheless, I have added the "legal" tag.

Comment: @franklin - If people don't know what a word means, it literally has "no meaning".

Comment: "look in dictionary"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several dictionaries list *scienter* as a noun. *[American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=scienter)* defines it as

> Knowledge that one's actions are wrong or contrary to law, where such knowledge is an element of a criminal offense or a basis for liability.

Similarly *[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/scienter)*

> The fact of an act having been done knowingly, especially as grounds for civil damages

Some list it as an adverb, such as *[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scienter)*

> (law) knowingly; wilfully

However, those listing it as an adverb do not give textual examples. I believe that they are actually referring to the phrase *with scienter*.

Effectively, *scienter* means *knowledge*, albeit of a special sort. As such it is a noun. I don't think most users of *scienter* would be troubled by the sentence

> When he took the money, he had scienter - he knew that it was illegal.

It means the same as

> When he took the money, he acted with scienter ...

Comment: I'd say this makes it genref.